Spire.Doc not able to run after proper installation for DOCX -> PDF conversion
I just wanted to export docx to pdf so installed Spire.Doc on my collab with:
%pip install Spire.Doc
%pip install plum-dispatch

and run the code
from spire.doc import *
from spire.doc.common import *

inputFile = "example-docs/document.docx"
outputFile = "document.pdf"

#Create word document
document = Document()
document.LoadFromFile(inputFile)

# Create a ToPdfParameterList object
parameters = ToPdfParameterList()

# Embed all used fonts in Word into PDF
parameters.IsEmbeddedAllFonts = True

#Save the file to a PDF file
document.SaveToFile("WordToPdfWithFontsEmbedded.pdf", parameters, FileFormat.PDF)
document.Close()

#Save the document to a PDF file.
# document.SaveToFile(outputFile, FileFormat.PDF)
# document.Close()

But I keep getting issue;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-707d9ebcb6c3> in <cell line: 15>()
     13 
     14 # Embed all used fonts in Word into PDF
---> 15 parameters.IsEmbeddedAllFonts = True
     16 
     17 #Save the file to a PDF file

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/spire/doc/common/__init__.py in CallCFunction(func, *args, **kwargs)
    103     args = list(args) +[data]
    104 
--> 105     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    106     modified_value = cast(data, POINTER(c_uint64)).contents.value
    107     if old_value != modified_value:

RuntimeError: ffi_prep_cif_var failed

What is the problem and how to fix this?

Spire.Doc for Python has not provided specific compatibility for Google Colab yet. However, I noticed that you mentioned macOS in another post. I would like to inform you that the latest version of Spire.Doc for Python V12.4.0 (released today) is compatible with macOS.
To install Spire.Doc for Python on Mac, you can refer to this documentation. If you encounter any issues on macOS, I would recommend posting them on Spire forum for help.
